# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using lidars over sodars for wind resource assessment?

Tags: renewables, wind-power

The process of wind resource assessment has used a variety of methods over the years; more recently, lidar  - radar-style sensing using lasers; and sodar (similar, but using sound) have come to dominate.

What the pros and cons of using lidar, over sodar, when assessing the wind resource at a potential windfarm site?